# Swift 1.2 cast [AnyObject?] to [AnyObject]

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

If you look at this function:

```
typealias JSONDictionary = [String: AnyObject]

private func allIdentifiersInJson(json: [JSONDictionary], key: String?) -> [AnyObject] {
        if let identifier = key {
            let identifiers = json.map{ $0[identifier] } //this returns [AnyObject?]
            return identifiers as? [AnyObject] ?? [] // this crashes the compiler in Release with Optimizations
        }
        return []
    }
```

How would you cast an [AnyObject?] to an [AnyObject]

In Release config with optimizations enabled, I get this error during compilation:

```
Bitcast requires both operands to be pointer or neither
  %548 = bitcast i64 %547 to %objc_object*, !dbg !10033
LLVM ERROR: Broken function found, compilation aborted!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on what is in my comment above, if you use the following, your app will crash if `identifier` is not a key in the dictionary:

```
let identifiers = json.map { $0[ identifier ]! }
```

So, what you might want to do is filter that first, then perform the mapping knowing that you can force unwrap because you've already checked for that key:

```
let identifiers = json.filter({ $0[ identifier ] != nil }).map { $0[ identifier ]! }
```

But if it were me, I'd want to get rid of the force unwrap altogether for total safety, even when someone else or even yourself comes back to this code a week later and monkeys with it by taking out the filter:

```
let identifiers = json.map({ $0[ identifier ] ?? NSNull() }).filter { !($0 is NSNull) }
```

Now you are safely unwrapping with the nil coalescing operator (`??`) and providing a default object (`NSNull`), then filtering out those default objects.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, this is a very comprehensive answer. I've learned a new thing today and I hope in the future that thinking functionally will become second nature.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use flatMap:

```
let l: [AnyObject?] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, nil, 7]
let m = l.flatMap { $0 } // Returns [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] as [AnyObject]
```

(tested only in Swift 2)

Comment: Thanks MirekE, that really works great in Swift2 but I'd need a solution for 1.2; Much appreciated though

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to be using something like this instead:

```
private func allIdentifiersInJson(json: [JSONDictionary], key: String?) -> [AnyObject] {
    if let key = key {
        return json.map { $0[key] }.filter { $0 != nil } as! [AnyObject]
    }
    return []
}
```

Because we are using `filter` to remove all instances of `nil`, we can use the forced cast to `[AnyObject]` without fear of a crash.

Or, as pointed out by @MirekE in their answer, `flatMap` is even more succinct:

```
return json.flatMap { $0[key] }
```

Which only returns non-nil results, and removes the need for any casting.

Answer (score 0):

This function will not crash the compiler:

```
private func allIdentifiersInJson(json: [JSONDictionary], key: String?) -> [AnyObject] {
    if let key = key {
        let identifiers = json.map{ $0[key]! } //this returns [AnyObject]
        return identifiers ?? []
    }
    return []
}
```

Comment: However, because of the precarious force unwrapping (`!`), this code will crash if the key is not found in the dictionary.  Using a force unwrap is still a bad idea, but with something like this you can at least know if won't crash with *some* certainty:  `let identifiers = json.filter({ $0[ identifier ] != nil }).map { $0[ identifier ]! }`